# php mysql select result that has no recored between two dates

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called "bookings" with rooms id & booking date

as

```
ID        Date
1         2018-04-20
1         2018-04-21
2         2018-04-20
4         2018-04-01
4         2018-04-02
4         2018-04-09
```

In html the user input the check in date and checkout date

what i want to do is find all rooms id's that has no dates equal or in between the check in and check out input dates...

for example if user input check in as: 2018-04-19 and checkout: 2018-04-21
then result should be : 4

how can i do this ?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why  it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time  to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers,  and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!  See also: [ask]

Answer (score 1):

You could use `NOT BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT * FROM `bookings` WHERE `date` NOT BETWEEN ? AND ?
```